# Google Cloud Platform - Server Error. Try again in 30 secs

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to upload my python code into Google Cloud. The files are working fine when I tested on the local machine via VS code.

But I get a server error from google cloud.

My files are:

```
main.py
requirements.txt
templates folder
```

**Copied some codes for the `app.yaml` (codes below)**

- runtime: python27
- api_version: 1
- threadsafe: true

**handlers:**

- url: `/static
  static_dir: static`
- url: `/.*
  script: main.app`

**libraries:**

- name: ssl
- version: latest

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit your question and add what error you're getting - otherwise we can just guess... Is "try again in 30 s" the only message ?